# In Swift how do you convert "&deg;" to "°" ( i.e degree symbol)? using built in Cocoa utility (with NSAttributedString)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

When I read the data from, say http://www.weather-forecast.com/, with the code below:

```
let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

The urlContent data is coming up as `"&deg;"`. How do you convert it to "°" (i.e degree symbol)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really isn't a good practice to go manually replacing HTML escape characters like this.  Cocoa has built in utilities to do this for you with `NSAttributedString`:

```
let input = "75&deg;, partly cloudy"

let options: [String : AnyObject] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute : NSUTF8StringEncoding]

if let data = input.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

    do {
        let unescaped = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        print(unescaped.string) // "75°, partly cloudy"
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a swift 3 solution too please..

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Go with the accepted answer for scalability. But if you have a weird case where you only want to replace a single kind of character this answer will do.

The degree symbol is represented in Swift by the string `\u{00B0}`. You can use this fact with `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString()` to do something like this:

```
let formattedUrlContent = urlContent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&deg;", withString: "\u{00B0}")
```

Comment: simple method. I was just complicating with different runtime handling options, thanks !

Comment: @Naishta As I've said in my answer, this really isn't the best way to unescape HTML characters.  Be warned when you have more characters to unescape in the future...

Answer (score 5):

this worked too in Swift 2.0 !

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&deg;", withString: "°")
```